# Multiple line verbatim environment

Tags: verbatim

I want to achieve the output shown below using multiple line verbatim

[image]

My attempt so far is

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
123
$\times$ 456
=============
738(this is $123 \times 6$)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This is definitely not what I need  and so I didn't write the code further.Can someone help me with the multiplication symbol and the desired result

Comment: Just use `\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape,basicstyle=\small\ttfamily]`. I think you need `123 x 6` instead of `\times`.

Comment: @HarishKumar But how can i get the multiplication symbol?

Comment: From the picture, it looks like `x` is the symbol.

Comment: Isn't this better (typographically) with a tabular environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one option, but are you sure you want this formatting?

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  mathescape=true,
  escapeinside=||
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
    123
 $\times$ 456
  ======
    738       (this is $123 \times 6$)
   615        (this is $123 \times 5$, shifted one position to the left)
 +492         (this is $123 \times 4$, shifted two positions to the left)
========
  56088
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes... I want exactly like this... Thanks a lot for the answer